# String addition or subtraction operators

Tags: c++, string, operators

How to add or subtract the value of string? For example:

```
    std::string number_string;
    std::string total;

    cout << "Enter value to add";
    std::getline(std::cin, number_string;
    total = number_string + number_string;
    cout << total;
```

This just append the string so this won't work. I know I can use int data type but I need to use string.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" strings?  Do you mean you have strings that contain numbers and you want to add those numbers?  Show us some example inputs and the output you'd like to see.

Comment: I mean adding like 1+3=4 ...

Comment: Why do you want to use a string to do math? Is it because an int is too small to hold the values you want to calculate? In which case, you should investigate "bignum" libraries.

Comment: C++ does not have any built-in functions to do what you ask. You need to write your own.

Comment: Those are integers, you mean "1" + "3" = "4"?

Comment: Yes, in this case user enter 3. So the output above should be 6.

Comment: Are you looking to add small (less than 10 digits or so) numbers, or very large numbers (more than about 10 digits)?

Comment: I will be entering user salary so I guess more than 10 digits.

Comment: @sg552 Salaries (in USD, pounds or Euro at least) will hardly overflow a signed 32bit integer. As long as you stay less than 2^31 you're fine with ints.

Comment: @Voo Would you suggest me using int or float for salaries...?

Comment: @sg552 In a practical program under absolutely no circumstances floats, fixed point math is the most sensible option for money. Makes it more complicated though, so you may want to start with floats for simplicity and then stumble upon the problems with them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `atoi(number_string.c_str())` to convert the string to an integer.

If you are concerned about properly handling non-numeric input, `strtol` is a better choice, albeit a little more wordy. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: `strtol(3)` is probably preferred over `atoi(3)` since it can return an error (via `errno`).

Comment: Good hint, amended answer.

Comment: @sftrabbit: not sure I agree that it's wise to throw C++11 answers at a newbie this year. Ask me again in 2015.

Comment: First I thought to downvote since there really should be no reason to use a c construct (both quite flawed in their own unique way), but then I remembered how horrible the c++ solution is itself, so carry on +1

Comment: The C++ way would be to use a `stringstream` but there's really no advantage; it's just more effort for the same answer.

Comment: The C++ way is to use `std::to_string(int)` if you have C++11, or `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(int)` otherwise.

Comment: @David Having to include boost for parsing an integer is hardly a great solution for a beginner. So the C++ way before c++11 would be `std::string s = "100"; int i; std::istringstream ss(s); ss >> i; char c; if (ss.fail() || ss.get(c)) // not a number` - which must be the most horrible int parsing code in any higher level language. Let's hope that c++11 becomes more widespread that we can forget this stuff.

Comment: But having Boost installed is almost essential for a beginner. It's a one-time cost that you have to pay (and a tiny one if you are lucky enough to be using a Linux distribution) that has a huge payoff for the rest of your C++ career.

Comment: @David And still I think it's more sensible for a beginner to learn about basic c++ and have fun writing simple programs before having to worry about linking (or first what the hell a dll/so is), setting the include paths correctly, etc. Both options aren't especially nice, but offering a blackbox code that works out of the box is less work and easier.

Comment: Maybe I'm spoiled because of my Linux experience, where it's just `sudo yum install boost-devel`, then in the source `#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`.

Comment: Depends pretty much on your distro there, last time I had some problems with paths not being correctly set under SUSE. But yes under linux it's fine if all goes right, but if the poor guy is under Windows (more likely I think) or Mac OS, it's no fun.

Comment: I absolutely disagree to the one who said beginners should be learning boost. Boost is a fantastic tool, but using it well requires a high knowledge of how C++ works. I don't expect an average learner will even attempt templates in the first year. I work with smart folks who I respect who would not be comfortable using Boost.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to work with integers the entire time, and then convert to a `std::string` at the very end.

Here is a solution that works if you have a C++11 capable compiler:

```
#include <string>

std::string sum(std::string const & old_total, std::string const & input) {
    int const total = std::stoi(old_total);
    int const addend = std::stoi(input);
    return std::to_string(total + addend);
}
```

Otherwise, use [boost](http://www.boost.org/):

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

std::string sum(std::string const & old_total, std::string const & input) {
    int const total = boost::lexical_cast<int>(old_total);
    int const addend = boost::lexical_cast<int>(input);
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(total + addend);
}
```

The function first converts each `std::string` into an `int` (a step that you will have to do, no matter what approach you take), then adds them, and then converts it back to a `std::string`. In other languages, like PHP, that try to guess what you mean and add them, they are doing this under the hood, anyway.

Both of these solutions have a number of advantages. They are [faster](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html), they report their errors with exceptions rather than silently appearing to work, and they don't require extra intermediary conversions.

The Boost solution does require a bit of work to set up, but it is definitely worth it. Boost is probably the most important tool of any C++ developer's work, except maybe the compiler. You will need it for other things because they have already done top-notch work solving many problems that you will have in the future, so it is best for you to start getting experience with it. The work required to install Boost is much less than the time you will save by using it.